# Json to multiple objects and using values to enumerate

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, razor

I have a small server shop that doesn't really need a database, so I decided to use a json file instead
The json file have multiple objects.

```
{
  "Windows": [
    {
      "Entry": {
        "Price": "900",
        "Cores": "2 vCPU",
        "RAM": "4GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "128GB Disk",
        "OS": "Windows Server"
      },
      "Medium": {
        "Price": "1400",
        "Cores": "4 vCPU",
        "RAM": "8GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "512GB Disk",
        "OS": "Windows Server"
      },
      "High": {
        "Price": "2000",
        "Cores": "8 vCPU",
        "RAM": "16GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "1TB Disk",
        "OS": "Windows Server"
      }
    }
  ],

  "Linux": [
    {
      "Entry": {
        "Price": "700",
        "Cores": "2 vCPU",
        "RAM": "4GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "128GB Disk",
        "OS": "Linux"
      },
      "Medium": {
        "Price": "1200",
        "Cores": "4 vCPU",
        "RAM": "8GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "512GB Disk",
        "OS": "Linux"
      },
      "High": {
        "Price": "1800",
        "Cores": "8 vCPU",
        "RAM": "16GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "1TB Disk",
        "OS": "Linux"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to break the objects in its individual parts to use it in a page where I can enumerate through the values, below is my approach to get the name of a property and its values

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetServers()
{
    using (var file = new StreamReader(*file directory*))
    {
         //Deserialize the file file into the RootObject
         var json = file.ReadToEnd();
         var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);

         //Read each object of the json file into a dictionary with the object key and the preceding values which is another object. 
         Type type = obj.GetType();
         PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
         var servers = new Dictionary<string, object>();

         foreach (var property in properties)
         {
             servers.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));
         }

         return servers;
    }
}
```

Here is the root object

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Window[] Windows { get; set; }
    public Linux[] Linux { get; set; }
}

public class Window
{
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    public Medium Medium { get; set; }
    public High High { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

public class High
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

public class Linux
{
    public Entry1 Entry { get; set; }
    public Medium1 Medium { get; set; }
    public High1 High { get; set; }
}

public class Entry1
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

public class Medium1
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

public class High1
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}
```

I want to enumerate through the windows server and split the objects.

So lets say I create a Page consisting of the servers that I offer
I want to enumerate through all the windows as well as the linux servers

Example of entry level server

```
foreach(var server in Root)
{
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    //Server Type (Windows or Linux)
                    <h4 class="p-2 m-0 text-center">@server.Key</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body p-3" id="card1">
                    //Server details 
                    <h3 class="fw-bold text-center my-3">@server.Value.Price</h3>
                    <p id="cores">@server.Value.Cores</p>
                    <p id="ram">@server.Value.RAM</p>
                    <p id="disk">@server.Value.Disk</p>
                    <p id="os"><i class="fa-brands fa-linux me-3 fa-xl"></i>@server.Value.OS</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-blue m-3">
                    View
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

An example of 1 card

[Card one example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMhxW.png)

But no matter what I do, I cant seem to find a solution of what I want
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are enumerating the properties. I would do something like this:

```
var rootObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>("JSON STRING");
List<object> servers = new List<object>();
servers.AddRange(rootObject.Windows);
servers.AddRange(rootObject.Linux);
```

Now you have both servers in one list.

Since both Windows and Linux are sharing the same properties, I would also declare an interface for them like this:

```
public interface IComputer 
{
    Entry Entry { get; set; }
    Medium Medium { get; set; }
    High High { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can replace `List<object>` with `List<IComputer>`. The benefit of this is you can access all properties easily with Intellisense.

Your classes will look like this then:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Window[] Windows { get; set; }
    public Linux[] Linux { get; set; }
}

public class Window : IComputer
{
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    public Medium Medium { get; set; }
    public High High { get; set; }
}

public class Linux : IComputer
{
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    public Medium Medium { get; set; }
    public High High { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

public class High
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd get rid of the redundant classes you use to deserialize your json, `Enty`, `Medium` and `High` all have the same properties for both `Windows` and `Linux` so they could all be of the same type, I'll just call it `Specs` for now.

Same goes for `Windows` and `Linux`, they could both be the same type. Let's just say `Platform` and give them a property for the platform name.

That leaves you with

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public Platform[] Platforms { get; set; }
}

public class Platform
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Specs Entry { get; set; }
    public Specs Medium { get; set; }
    public Specs High { get; set; }
}

public class Specs
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}
```

You'll have to do some small adjustments to your json

```
{
  "Platforms": [
    {
      "Name": "Windows",
      "Entry": {
        "Price": "900",
        "Cores": "2 vCPU",
        "RAM": "4GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "128GB Disk",
        "OS": "Windows Server"
      },
      "Medium": {
        "Price": "1400",
        "Cores": "4 vCPU",
        "RAM": "8GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "512GB Disk",
        "OS": "Windows Server"
      },
      "High": {
        "Price": "2000",
        "Cores": "8 vCPU",
        "RAM": "16GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "1TB Disk",
        "OS": "Windows Server"
      }      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Linux",
      "Entry": {
        "Price": "700",
        "Cores": "2 vCPU",
        "RAM": "4GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "128GB Disk",
        "OS": "Linux"
      },
      "Medium": {
        "Price": "1200",
        "Cores": "4 vCPU",
        "RAM": "8GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "512GB Disk",
        "OS": "Linux"
      },
      "High": {
        "Price": "1800",
        "Cores": "8 vCPU",
        "RAM": "16GB vRAM",
        "Disk": "1TB Disk",
        "OS": "Linux"
      }
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Also you can directly iterate your `Platform` array in your razor code and display  their properties. There's no real point to doing it through reflection unless you want to be able to add properties to your classes later on without changing the GUI,
which does not seem to be what you're trying to do.

PS: I'd reevaluate if the shop really does not need some sort of database in the future. Requirements change and a bunch of json files might get messy later on.

Comment: Reason for not using a database is that I only am going to use these 6 servers and will not be adding more, the json file allows a tolerance for maybe 3 or 4 additional servers so using a database seems a bit overkill for me.

Comment: You are welcome. If this is a project for yourself where only you define the requirements then flat files can be the way to go. It's only when it's for a business that this can become a problem fast because in my experience it never stays at "We only need this one feature" ;-)

Comment: Say I do use a database, I may only be using 2 tables, will it be worth it to host an instance for this small case?

Comment: There are tons of different solutions that vary in complexity and features, not all need to be "hosted" as in served by a different application/server. SQLite for example can be just enough for many simple scenarios but is not great if multiple applications need to access your database

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it! I think I will stick to the json file for now and perhaps when necessary migrate to a database

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate using this algorithm, and you only need one class

```
var servers = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
      .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Entry>[]>>(json);

    foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(server.Key); // "windows" or "lunix"
        foreach (var os in server.Value)
        {
            foreach (var entry in os)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key); // "entry","medium", or "high"

            Console.WriteLine(entry.Value.Price);
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Value.Cores);
            //....
            }
        }
    }

public class Entry
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Cores { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string Disk { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}
```

PS  don't need any classes, if you add one more dictionary

```
var servers = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]>>(json);

    foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(server.Key);
        foreach (var os in server.Value)
        {
            foreach (var entry in os)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);

                Console.WriteLine(entry.Value["Price"]);
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Value["Cores"]);
                //....
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought of using a dictionary of dictionaries but the solution seems a bit messy and hard to keep track of all the key value pairs, but thank you for the help! : )